# Encoding countably many reals

Tags: set-theory

Is there a way to encode a countable set of reals by a set theoretic formula with parameters a countable sequence of ordinals?

By this I mean is there a formula $\varphi$ in the language of set theory such that 
$X=\{x \in \mathbb{R}| \varphi(x)\}$ and furthermore the only parameter in $\varphi$ is a countable sequence $s$ of ordinals.

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate a little more, what are your thoughts, etc...

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that $\Bbb R^\omega$ and $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality, so we can prove in $\sf ZF$ that there is a bijection between the two sets.

We say that a countable set of reals $A$ is encoded by a real $x$, if $x$ as a sequence of reals has a range which is exactly $A$. The axiom of choice does play a role here, and it plays the role for allowing us to choose a code for every countable set.

If all sets are Lebesgue measurable, for example, then we can show that $\Bbb R$ and $[\Bbb R]^\omega$ have different cardinalities, despite the fact that $\Bbb R$ can be mapped onto $[\Bbb R]^\omega$ (by decoding a sequence and mapping it to its range), and of course $\Bbb R$ can be mapped into $[\Bbb R]^\omega$ injectively as well.

This fact shows that you cannot do this uniformly in $\sf ZF$ without some appeal to a choice function, but every countable set has at least one real which encodes it. And such real is that parameter you're looking for.

Comment: So we can find a formula (assuming choice) which defines a countable set of reals such that this formula has only a real as a parameter, right?

Comment: Without choice. Choice is only needed if you want to uniformly choose a parameter for each set, since for every countable set there are continuum many parameters (well, for countably infinite sets).

Comment: What do you mean by $[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$?

Comment: All the countably infinite subsets of $\Bbb R$.